# Blank navigation in chrome for android [ issue also on bootstrap's website & all websites using bootstrap ]

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

i am creating a responsive website with bootstrap and i am getting some weird issue with navigation in only chrome on android i checked & the same problem exists on bootstrap's own website to see it

1. Open bootstrap [ http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ ] or any website using bootstrap in chrome on android
2. then click on menu to open, then close & then click again to open
3. this time the navigation is coming blank even thought the links are there and can be clicked but can't be seen [ see screenshots lin attached --- i have same problem on my site ]

Screenshot Links:

1. http://goo.gl/5N5spG

is there a way to fix it or any other info that i can make it work

Thanks

Comment: Anyone ?? any idea on this ?? i would say this is something to look at as a LOT of websites may be even yours might be using bootstrap :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say I understand *why* this is happening, but this css override seems to fix it:

```
.nav-collapse {
    -webkit-transform: none;
}
```