# Bootstrap responsive menu dropdown not showing submenues after 2 3 times

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 2.1.1 Problem is on android mobile and chrome browser. I have tried it on iPhone and its working fine there.

There is a problem with Bootstrap responsive menu on android device its working fine in desktop browser but in android mobile and chrome browser, when i click it and its pull down and all sub-menus will shown, but when i try it again all sub menus are gone means hide and not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now found the answer on this page [Blank navigation in chrome for android [ issue also on bootstrap's website & all websites using bootstrap ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335009/blank-navigation-in-chrome-for-android-issue-also-on-bootstraps-website-all/20655785#20655785)

There appears to be a bug in Bootstrap that is incorrectly setting

```
.nav-collapse {
    -webkit-transform: no;
}
```

instead of

```
.nav-collapse {
    -webkit-transform: none;
}
```